# Django Row-Level Permissions on a Model With django-rules

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-authentication

I have a django project with two models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

I would like to control which rows in these models each user can access. My groups in `auth_group` correspond to `team` in the `Project` model.

How would I use `django-rules` to restrict user access to `Task` rows based on `Project` `team`? Let's say there is `Team X`, and John Smith has been placed in `group` `Team X`. How should `django-rules` be used to only allow John Smith to see tasks that are tied to projects for `Team X`?

I'm not sure how to access `Team` in order to compare it to the groups the user is a part of. Unsure to the point where I don't have any workable code to show for it. The difficulty comes in the fact that it has to traverse a foreign key. In addition, each row (`team`) has to be checked against each group a user is a part of.